# Xpath: How to get nth child of nth child

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get the nth child of nth child. Code looks like this

```
<div class="target-class">
   <div class="another-div">
      <div class="another-target-class">
         text goes here
      </div>
      <div class="another-target-class">
         text goes here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="target-class">
   <div class="another-div">
      <div class="another-target-class">
         text goes here
      </div>
      <div class="another-target-class">
         text goes here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="target-class">
   <div class="another-div">
      <div class="another-target-class">
         text goes here
      </div>
      <div class="another-target-class">
         text goes here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can target first "target-class" with this Xpath:
`(//div[contains(@class, 'target-class')])[1]`

I can also target "another-target-class" with this Xpath:
`(//div[@class="another-target-class"])[1]`

What I need and can't get running is the combination oh these two Xpaths, something like this:
`(//div[contains(@class, 'target-class')])[1](//div[@class="another-target-class"])[1]`

Plus: The solution must work not only with [1] but also with [2], [3] and so on.

Any help is much appreciated :-) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
/descendant::div[@class='target-class'][1]
  /descendant::div[@class="another-target-class"][1]
```

Note: `//` is a useful shorthand for simple queries, but it doesn't play nicely with positions, so using the `descendant` axis explicitly can be clearer.

I don't know whether there was any reason you used `contains()` rather than `"="` in your code, so I changed it to `"="` because it's simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael - works like charm and is exactly what I was looking for.

Also thank you for explaining _why_ it works. Much appreciated!